# Flutter on tap Bounce fixed at one position when scrolled

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-widget

I am working `On Tap Bounce` feature on my widget. I have referred to these links for information:

- [Bouncing Button Flutter](https://alltechsavvy.com/how-to-create-a-bouncing-button-in-flutter/)
- [Create on tap bounce on flutter](https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-create-bouncing-animation-in-flutter/)

I got this package named as [bouncing_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/bouncing_widget), which was good enough for the workaround, but there is one limitation to it, i.e., **It is not good for scrolling widget. You cannot scroll the page by tapping on the widget which uses this flutter bouncing widget**

Somebody has already created a bug for the above widget, and no solution is found. Here is where you can find the issue: [Bouncing Widget GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ThomasEcalle/bouncing_widget/issues/1)

So, I decided to make my own widget which does the job for me. I have made the widget, and it works fine, but there is a limitation, i.e.,

> When you scroll the page by holding on the widget, the widget stays there in one fixed position, that means, like it remains in pressed position

**Here is my code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CLBounceWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onPressed;
  final Widget child;

  CLBounceWidget({Key key, @required this.onPressed, @required this.child}): super(key:key);

  @override
  CLBounceWidgetState createState() => CLBounceWidgetState();
}

class CLBounceWidgetState extends State<CLBounceWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  double _scale;
  final Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: 200);
  AnimationController _animationController;

  //Getting onPressed Calback
  VoidCallback get onPressed => widget.onPressed;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: duration,
      lowerBound: 0.0,
      upperBound: 0.1
    )..addListener((){ setState((){}); });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _animationController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scale = 1 - _animationController.value;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: _onTapDown,
      onTapUp: _onTapUp,
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: _scale,
        child: widget.child
      )
    );
  }

  // Triggering the onPressed callback with a check
  void _onTapTrigger(){
    if(onPressed != null){
      onPressed();
    }
  }

  //Start the animation
  _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details){
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  // We revise the animation and notify the user of the event
  _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details){
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (){
      _animationController.reverse();
    });

    //Finally calling the callback function
    _onTapTrigger();
  }
}
```

**Also:** I have tried doing this, without using `Future`, but with that, *Animation only happens when long pressed*, just **_onTapTrigger()** works:

```
_onTapUp(TapUpDetails details){
  _animationController.reverse();
  _onTapTrigger();
}
```

**Tried:** I have tried using `onLongPress`, `onLongPressEnd`, `onLongPressMoveUpdate` to at least do the **_animationController.reverse();**, but nothing worked out for me.

I want the widget to stay normal when I scroll the page while holding the widget, like a normal widget performs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, after a long more researches, and hours and hours of toil, I finally found out what I was willing to have in my project. **I have created a package on flutter [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) to help other developers in need of what the package `flutter_bounce` has to offer.**

You can search for `flutter_bounce` on the above link, or you can directly go to this: [flutter_bounce](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bounce)

To make use of it, you just need to do this:

```
Bounce(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 110),
  onPressed: (){ YOUR_FUNCTION },
  child: YOUR_WIDGET
)
```

For more details, please feel free to read the `README` of the link. It has all necessary details. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Another new package that you guys can try is [flutter_bounceable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bounceable) that I've developed. If you guys prefer a much more simple, interactive and customizable bounce widget, then this package is just for you.

```dart
Bounceable(
  onTap: yourFunction, // set to null if want to disable bounceable
  child: YourWidget(),
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), // optional
  reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), // optional
  curve: Curves.decelerate, // optional
  reverseCurve: Curves.decelerate, // optional
);
```